# Avoid parsing code in pre and code HTML tags in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net, prettify

I need to display some code and highlight its syntax using `prettifier` which requires the code to be wrapped inside `pre` and `code` tags. But ASP.net parses the code present within these tags and displays an error on compilation. How do I avoid the code present in these tags from being parsed?

Comment: What error are you having?

Comment: I actually want to display some .aspx code on the webpage. I wrap the .aspx code that i want to display on the webpage within the `pre` tag but the compiler also parses whatever is inside the `pre` tag. Hence it displays the error according to whats present in the `pre` tag.

Comment: @thunderbird, A code sample in your question would help us a lot.  Are you converting `'<'`, `'>'`, and `'&'` characters in the code you want to display?  Prettify assumes that what you've got is code expressed as HTML, so you still need to escape the content as you would to put it in a `<pre>` tag if prettify was not running.

Comment: @MikeSamuel is there any tools that converts a piece of code to html. I was simply putting the entire code without any html formatting in the `pre` tags.

Comment: @thunderbird, http://www.htmlescape.net/htmlescape_tool.html looks like it should do what you want, but I have never used it.

Comment: @MikeSamuel thx i think that will help.